# SQL Need two WHERE clause conditions

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need a conditional `Where` clause or `Case` statement based on a table field's value.

This is what I have and it's not working:

```
Select n.id, n.message, n.Type
From Notifications n
Where
(
      n.Type = 1 
      And ApplicationMask & isnull(@applicationMask,2147483647)<> 0
      And Cast(GETDATE() as Date) Between Cast(StartDate AS Date) and
                                             Cast(EndDate as Date) 
      And Not Exists(Select notificationID 
                     From NotificationDelivery nd 
                     Where nd.NotificationID = n.id 
                     and nd.UserID = @userID)

 )
 OR
 (
      n.Type = 2 
      And ApplicationMask & ISNULL(@applicationMask,2147483647) <> 0
      And Cast(GETDATE() as Date) Between Cast(StartDate AS Date) and 
                                           Cast(EndDate as Date)      
 )
```

The `OR` is messing it up, I think.  The top `Where` clause works by itself, but like this it is returning rows that it should not return. It seems like the `NOT EXIST` part is being ignored. Is there a better way? I am not too strong in SQL queries.

Comment: Did you mean to add the `NOT EXISTS` part in the second half of the query?

Comment: Do you want the `NOT EXISTS`to apply to both the top and the bottom variants?

Comment: "Not working" and "returning rows that it should not return" is not awfully specific. Can you be more concrete?

Comment: What is this ampersand sign doing there `And ApplicationMask & isnull(@applicationMask,2147483647)`

Comment: The ampersand is doing a bitwise AND operation. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174965.aspx

Comment: Do you only want to the `NOT EXISTS` to apply to the first condition, or should it apply to both sides of the `OR` statements?  It looks like you are only wanting to show notifications that have not been delivered, is this correct? In this case you may be better off doing a `LEFT JOIN` where NotificaitonDelivery.NotificationID is null

Comment: Please add the purpose of the query, the expected results, and more details about what is being returned that "should not return" when using the current query.  There are a lot of assumptions that would have to be made with your current question.  Also what are the data types of StartDate/EndDate columns? If they are `DATETIME`, then you are better off not casting them as a `DATE` b/c then SQL Server can't use any indexes on those columns.

Comment: The NOT EXIST should apply to the first where clause.  Basically, what I am trying to accomplish is this:  Get a sum for the bitwise applicationMask in the notification table.  Then check the NotificationDelivery table to see if a type 1 has been read, if true, then don't show this notification any more...the Type 2 is a notification that must be seen every time between the date parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this for better performance and better readability. I assume this will return the result you need:

```
set @applicationMask = isnull(@applicationMask,1)

Select n.id, n.message, n.Type
From Notifications n
Where
Type in (1,2) 
And ApplicationMask = 1
And @applicationMask > 0
And dateadd(d, 0, datediff(d, -1, GETDATE()) > StartDate
And dateadd(d, 0, datediff(d, 0, GETDATE())) <= EndDate
And (type = 2 or Not Exists(Select null 
                From NotificationDelivery nd 
                Where nd.NotificationID = n.id 
                and nd.UserID = @userID))
```

Comment: Thank you, you got it, although the datediff part was not giving me the correct results so I just put the BETWEEN back in there and worked  like I needed.

Comment: @user3461552 are you sure that part didn't work ? That part was suppose to tune your script. It looks valid to me. Making a small modification to match other datatypes than datetime

Answer (score 0):

Totally untested but how about structuring the SQL like this:

```
Select n.id, n.message, n.Type
  From Notifications n
 Where 1=1
   And (ApplicationMask & ISNULL(@applicationMask,2147483647) <> 0
   And Cast(GETDATE() as Date) Between Cast(StartDate AS Date) 
   And Cast(EndDate as Date))     
    OR (ApplicationMask & isnull(@applicationMask,2147483647)<> 0 
   And Cast(GETDATE() as Date) Between Cast(StartDate AS Date) 
   And Cast(EndDate as Date) 
   And Not Exists(Select notificationID 
                    From NotificationDelivery nd 
                   Where nd.NotificationID = n.id 
                     and nd.UserID = @userID))
```

Just an idea...Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest just splitting your two conditions into two queries and UNION the result

```
SELECT  n.id, n.message, n.Type
FROM    Notifications n
WHERE   n.Type = 1
    AND ApplicationMask & isnull(@applicationMask,2147483647)<> 0
    AND Cast(GETDATE() as Date) Between Cast(StartDate AS Date) and
                                     Cast(EndDate as Date) 
    AND Not Exists(Select notificationID 
             From NotificationDelivery nd 
             Where nd.NotificationID = n.id 
             and nd.UserID = @userID)

UNION

SELECT  n.id, n.message, n.Type
FROM    Notifications n
WHERE   n.Type = 2 
    AND ApplicationMask & ISNULL(@applicationMask,2147483647) <> 0
    AND Cast(GETDATE() as Date) Between Cast(StartDate AS Date) and 
                                       Cast(EndDate as Date)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try to narrow down the dataset and filter on that something like -

```
Select
 n.id, n.message, n.Type
From (select n.id, n.message, n.Type
    from Notifications
    WHERE
    n.Type in (1, 2 )
    And ApplicationMask & ISNULL(@applicationMask,2147483647) <> 0
        And Cast(GETDATE() as Date) Between Cast(StartDate AS Date) and 
                                           Cast(EndDate as Date) 
    ) n

Where  not (n.Type =1 
        And Not Exists(Select notificationID 
                     From NotificationDelivery nd 
                     Where nd.NotificationID = n.id 
                     and nd.UserID = @userID)
        )
```